# Why does the float having 5 as its last decimal digit give the correct output in floating point comparisons,while in other cases it is not?

Tags: c++, c, floating-point, precision

I have already asked this question, but the answer to this specific subpart is not clear to me. See the code below:

```
float f=2.5;
if (f==2.5)
printf("abc");
else
printf("xyz"); //prints abc
```

I know that if we had taken `2.2` instead of `2.5`, it would output the opposite as float is taken as double and floating point nos. Shouldn't they be equated actually? I want to know why there is an exception with the numbers having their last decimal digit `5`.

Comment: 0.5 is 1/2. (0.1 base 2)

Comment: Which part of the more upvoted answer to your other question on this topic is not clear ?  Read also the second most upvoted answer to the question of which your other question is a duplicate.

Answer (score 5):

Because it can be expressed as an integer times an integral power of 2. E.g. 2.5 = 5/2 = 5×(2<sup>-1</sup>). This matches directly the common representation of a floating point value.

Comment: Times an *integral* power of 2. Just sayin' ;-)

Comment: Every real number can be expressed that way. it is only a matter of bits - sometimes an infinite number ...

Comment: @Olaf: rational numbers, strictly.

Comment: @Olaf: And not even all rational numbers; 1/3 simply cannot be represented that way.

Comment: @MSalters: Notice the last part of my comment. Which is the actual crux.

Comment: @Bathsheba: Notice the last part of my comment. Which is the actual crux

Comment: @MSalters: You *almost* can, see the standard way of proving Urysohn's lemma.

Comment: @Olaf: That sadly will never apply to irrationals.

Comment: @Bathsheba: I might miss something, but isn't their point that they require an infinite number of digits for their representation? So if you **had** an infinite number of digits, what would be the problem?

Comment: The central tenet is that an irrational number cannot be written as a / b, no matter how big a and b are.

Comment: @Bathsheba: Yes, I know that. It also reqires `a` and `b` being integers. But I never required that. Maybe I should emphasize that I indeed mean _infinite_, not "a very large number of". Apparently this is not possible.

Comment: @Olaf: Obviously, we're talking about integers. Any real number `x` can be written as `a/b` if you drop that condition, that's trivial : `a=x, b=1`. As for "an infinite number of digits", note that the set of integers is already unbounded. There's no finite upper bound, and therefore no finite number of digits either.

Comment: @MSalters: "Any real number x can be written as a/b" - You mean "rationale number". Real numbers include those which can't be as pointed out by bathsheba. That's why I added this clarification. But you missed the actual point of my comment, which is exactly the reason for OPs problem.

Comment: @Olaf: No, i precisely mean what I wrote. Any real number `x` can be written as `a/b` if and only if you drop the condition that `a` and `b` are integers. But that's trivial, so a∈ℕ is implied.

Comment: @MSalters: Not clear why you criticize my addition about the integers. Please read the thread carefully again.

Comment: "can be expressed as an integer times a power of 2" has its limitations.  `1 + pow(2,-25)`  an be represented exactly as decimal text and "as an integer times a power of 2", yet will not compare equally due to finite precision of binary floating point - still a good observation.

Comment: @chux: I believe ordinary 64-bits IEEE  754, as is commonly used for the default floating point type `double` in C++, has around 52 bits for the mantissa.

Comment: @Bathsheba: Thanks, fixed the wording. :)

Comment: Have an upvote!

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf [binary64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) has 53 bits of numerical significance (52 explicitly coded).  The issue of my comment applies with the narrower `float f=...;` with its 24 bits of significance and how `1 + pow(2,-25)`  would not store exactly as `float` even though it meets this answer criteria.

Comment: @chux: Feel free to amend the answer, please. I chose to not discuss limits of representation because the OP is struggling with a much more fundamental issue. But I think he/she got the idea by now. :)

Answer (score 5):

`2.5` can be written as a *dyadic rational*, and given that it is also of sufficiently small magnitude, it can be represented *exactly* in IEEE754 floating point. `2.25` can also be represented perfectly too, for example. Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_rational

---

> floating point nos. shouldnt be equated actually

This is little more than a rule of thumb. And arbitrary comparision using badly thought out tolerances can be harmful. There is nothing mysterious about floating point. It's only that most of them cannot be represented as decimals (which is what developers tend to think in), that's all.

Comment: You probably meant times instead of plus, and I think it wouldn't hurt to use common speech “power of two” or “binary fraction” rather than the math-ish “dyadic rational”.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: I was attempting to think of this as a "proper fraction". There's no real need for that, so I've removed it.

Comment: Good ref to _dyadic rational_.  Also need "... of sufficiently small magnitude _and limited precision_" - same reason as in this [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42085272/why-does-the-float-having-5-as-its-last-decimal-digit-give-the-correct-output-in/42085325?noredirect=1#comment71356312_42085325)

Answer (score 0):

If you measure a distance, how many millimeters is it? And is it not a tiny bit more or a tiny bit less? And if you zoom in on your yardstick, how many micrometers is it? And not a bit more or a bit less?

This to illustrate that floating point uses bits to represent an *approximation* of a value and cannot (cannot always) represent the exact value.

Comment: the question is about why two floating points can be compared to be equal in that particular example, not why the cannot be compared in the general case

Answer (score 0):

The number 2.5 passes the test because 0.5 has an exact representation as a binary fraction. It is 2<sup>-1</sup>. In fact, every negative power of 2 has 5 as its last digit. Here are a few examples

```
2^-1  = 0.5000000000000000
2^-2  = 0.2500000000000000
2^-3  = 0.1250000000000000
2^-4  = 0.0625000000000000
2^-5  = 0.0312500000000000
2^-6  = 0.0156250000000000
2^-7  = 0.0078125000000000
2^-8  = 0.0039062500000000
2^-9  = 0.0019531250000000
2^-10 = 0.0009765625000000
2^-11 = 0.0004882812500000
```

Things to note:

1. Most implementations of the C language express floating point
   numbers as the sum of negative powers of 2 (the sum itself is then
   multiplied by a power of 2).
2. The pattern you see above will continue for all negative powers of
   2 . That's because when the 50 at the end is divided by 2, it's always going to yield a number with a 5 at the end, and that 5 will
   be one more decimal place to the right.
3. When you sum any combination of the negative powers of 2, the
   smallest number will always contribute the 5 at the end of the
   number, and that 5 will not be summed with a non-zero digit from any
   of the larger numbers.

So all numbers with an exact representation end with 5. However, that's not to say that every number that ends in 5 has an exact representation.  For example 0.385 does not have an exact representation, and will fail the equality test.

Comment: That's not the actual problem. The actual problem is the limited number of bits available.